# What is a copresheaf on a "precategory"?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a category with pullbacks. A **precategory** $\mathbb{C}$ in the sense of Borceux and Janelidze [*Galois Theories*, §7.2] comprises three objects $C_0, C_1, C_2$ in $\mathcal{S}$ and morphisms $d_2^0, d_2^1, d_2^2 : C_2 \to C_1$, $d_1^0, d_1^1 : C_1 \to C_0$, $s_0^0 : C_0 \to C_1$, satisfying the following fragment of the simplicial identities:
\begin{align}
d_1^0 \circ d_2^0 & = d_1^0 \circ d_1^1 \\
d_1^0 \circ d_2^2 & = d_1^1 \circ d_2^0 \\
d_1^1 \circ d_2^1 & = d_1^1 \circ d_2^2 \\
d_1^0 \circ s_0^0 & = \textrm{id}_{C_0} \\
d_1^1 \circ s_0^0 & = \textrm{id}_{C_0}
\end{align}
If you squint hard enough, you will see that any internal category in $\mathcal{S}$ gives rise to a precategory:
\begin{align}
d_1^0 & = \text{codomain} \\
d_1^1 & = \text{domain} \\
s_0^0 & = \text{identity arrow} \\
d_2^0 & = \text{second arrow of a composable pair of arrows} \\
d_2^1 & = \text{composite of a composable pair of arrows} \\
d_2^2 & = \text{first arrow of a composable pair of arrows}
\end{align}

Now, Borceux and Janelidze go on to define the category of "covariant presheaves" (i.e. a **copresheaf**) on $\mathbb{C}$ as the pseudolimit (or bilimit... I'm not entirely certain) of the induced pseudocommutative diagram of pullback functors

$$(\mathcal{S} \downarrow C_2) \mathrel{\hbox{$\begin{matrix} \smash{\leftarrow} \newline \smash{\leftarrow} \newline \smash{\leftarrow} \end{matrix}$}} (\mathcal{S} \downarrow C_1) \mathrel{\hbox{$\begin{matrix} \smash{\leftarrow} \newline \smash{\rightarrow} \newline \smash{\leftarrow} \end{matrix}$}} (\mathcal{S} \downarrow C_0)$$
but can we describe this category explicitly? It seems to me that a copresheaf on $\mathbb{C}$ is determined by a morphism $p_0 : F_0 \to C_0$ in $\mathcal{S}$ together with a choice of pullbacks
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
F_1 & \overset{\hat{d}_1^0}{\to} & F_0 \\
{\scriptstyle p_1} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle p_0} \\
C_1 & \underset{d_1^0}{\to} & C_0
\end{array}
\hspace{3.0ex}
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_0 & \overset{\hat{s}_0^0}{\to} & F_1 \\
{\scriptstyle p_1} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle p_0} \\
C_0 & \underset{s_0^0}{\to} & C_1
\end{array}
\hspace{3.0ex}
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_1 & \overset{\hat{d}_1^1}{\to} & F_0 \\
{\scriptstyle p_1} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle p_0} \\
C_1 & \underset{d_1^1}{\to} & C_0
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
F_2 & \overset{\hat{d}_2^0}{\to} & F_1 \\
{\scriptstyle p_2} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle p_1} \\
C_2 & \underset{d_2^0}{\to} & C_1
\end{array}
\hspace{3.0ex}
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_2 & \overset{\hat{d}_2^1}{\to} & F_1 \\
{\scriptstyle p_2} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle p_1} \\
C_2 & \underset{d_2^1}{\to} & C_1
\end{array}
\hspace{3.0ex}
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_2 & \overset{\hat{d}_2^2}{\to} & F_1 \\
{\scriptstyle p_2} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle p_1} \\
C_2 & \underset{d_2^2}{\to} & C_1
\end{array}$$
such that the "hatted" version of the simplicial identities are satisfied. But this seems to be saying that a copresheaf on a precategory is another precategory, and that doesn't sound right at all.

So, what *is* a copresheaf on a precategory?

**Edit.** After some further thought, I now see that if $\mathbb{C}$ is actually an internal category in $\mathcal{S}$, then the above defines a copresheaf on which $\mathbb{C}$ acts invertibly, and the internal category structure apparent in this definition is exactly the category of elements of the copresheaf. (In other words, we are identifying copresheaves with [discrete opfibrations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+fibration).) So maybe this is correct after all...